# Using the same function in scipy quad and dblquad

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, scipy

I'm trying to get a single lambda function to work with both scipy's quad and dblquad command.  In the context of what I'm doing, the integral will always be single variable, but has variable bounds.

Here's what I've got:

```
import scipy.integrate as inte

df1 = lambda x: x
df2 = lambda x,y: x

inte.quad(df1,0,10)[0]

inte.dblquad(df2,0,10,lambda x: 0, lambda x: x)[0]
```

In the code above, df1 and df2 are effectively the same thing, but that superficial second argument is required for the code to work. Ideally, I'd like both quad and dblquad to work with just one lambda function, but I'm unaware of anyway to make this work.  Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: hi. I realize this question is a few years old, but I'm having the same issues. Did you perhaps find a solution, how to perform dual integration (integrating twice) on a function with a single variable?

Comment: hey, I never really found a good answer, I don't think.  If I remember right, I made a function that had a `try, catch` block that ran the function with a single variable at first, and then if it errored out, would try it with the unused second variable.  This did what I needed, but still felt awful to write...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `dblquad` requires a function of two variables.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to integrate twice the function with a single variable?